# What configuration involved in redirect to www domain from without www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

Try to be thorough because this is so much trouble when someone else left and new IT comes, then just could not figure out why this domain without www is kept being redirected ( from the server side, because nothing to see from developer toolbar) to the `www` domain.

I have fair amount of know-how about Apache and .htaccess. I check logs. Yes, the request hit the log. And browser cache, yes, I clean them up. Try incognito mode etc.The redirect still goes on.

I tried to grep the word `www` under `/etc/apache2`, nothing useful

Anyways, anyone have a better idea? Please share more insight.

Comment: is there `.htaccess` file anywhere in your website folder?

Comment: Wasn't there the idea in some browser projects to visually remove the ``www.`` prefix from URLs (since it is idiotic anyway)? Just asking, because you, if I understand correctly, claim that there is _not_ redirection happening...

Comment: Actually it is Drupal 8. So I checked .htaccess and web.config both has explicit handling about www redirect which are all commented out. That only makes me more lost. As far as I have seen, some browser removing the www or what would be the browser hiding it from seeing.When you click on it and try to copy, you see the full URL.